# Keyed eigensystem for nested Association

Tags: function-construction, associations, query

Suppose a matrix is given where both rows and columns are keyed, for example this correlation matrix:

```
ds = <|"ERE"-><|"ERE"->1.`,"MDE"->0.5`,"PTB"->0.5`,"MDP12"->0.6`|>,"MDE"-><|"ERE"->0.5`,"MDE"->1.`,"PTB"->0.1`,"MDP12"->0.8`|>,"PTB"-><|"ERE"->0.5`,"MDE"->0.1`,"PTB"->1.`,"MDP12"->0.1`|>,"MDP12"-><|"ERE"->0.6`,"MDE"->0.8`,"PTB"->0.1`,"MDP12"->1.`|>|>
```

What is the minimal amount of work to get matrix functions such as `Eigensystem` to be output in keyed form?

If keys are projected out, then `Eigensystem` can be called on the underlying value matrix:

```
ds // Query[Values, Values] // Eigensystem
```

> {{2.38557,1.096,0.34121,0.177218},{{-0.545044,-0.546841,-0.277419,-0.571779},{0.296227,-0.364221,0.81849,-0.33116},{0.724656,-0.497105,-0.476972,0.0160709},{-0.300084,-0.566741,0.160034,0.750429}}}

The desired keyed format would have an association for the eigenvalues and a nested Association for the Eigenvector matrix:

```
ds // keyedEigensystem
```

> ```
> {<|ERE->2.38557,MDE->1.096,PTB->0.34121,MDP12->0.177218|>,<|ERE-><|ERE->-0.545044,MDE->-0.546841,PTB->-0.277419,MDP12->-0.571779|>,MDE-><|ERE->0.296227,MDE->-0.364221,PTB->0.81849,MDP12->-0.33116|>,PTB-><|ERE->0.724656,MDE->-0.497105,PTB->-0.476972,MDP12->0.0160709|>,MDP12-><|ERE->-0.300084,MDE->-0.566741,PTB->0.160034,MDP12->0.750429|>|>}
> ```

Current solution is cumbersome, and would likely need mod for rectangular matrices and functions like `SingularValueDecomposition`. Is there a simpler, more flexible method?

```
keyedEgensystem[as_Association]:=Query[{{Keys,Query[Transpose/*Keys]},Query[Values,Values]/*Eigensystem}]/*Replace[{{rowKeys_,colKeys_},{l_,M_}}:>{AssociationThread[rowKeys,l],Query[AssociationThread[rowKeys,\[Bullet]],AssociationThread[colKeys,\[Bullet]]][M]}][as]
```

PS using the shorthand pseudo-op form

```
\[Bullet] /: h_[pre___, \[Bullet], post___] := 
  Function[expr, h[pre, expr, post]];
```